# How to disable Ctrl + Shift + UP Arrow shortcut on Windows 10

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, windows-10, shortcuts

How should I disable <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>UP Arrow</kbd> shortcut on Windows 10? Its opening Microsoft Edge which is searching for results for my clipboard content from Bing.

Comment: Try right clicking on the Microsoft Edge shortcut on your desktop. (If you don't have one make one). When the dialog window pops up, go to the `Shortcut` tab and see if the `Shortcut Key` input box has the `Ctrl+Shift+↑` as a shortcut. If so, delete it.

Comment: For me it's _Ctrl + Shift + N_

Answer (score 0):

1. Click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>
2. Go to Settings
3. Go to Manage hot keys
4. Click disable
5. Click apply

Comment: I press Ctrl + Shift + F12, but nothing happens